# MySQL IF...THEN syntax error

Tags: mysql, if-statement, syntax

I've been trying to work with the `IF` statement in MySQL (v5.6.13) without any success. I've eventually pared my code back to the simple example below, which still doesn't work:

```
IF 10>1 THEN
    SELECT 10;
END IF;
```

When I run this, it gives me the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF 10>1 THEN
    SELECT 10' at line 1
```

I did wonder whether it was something to do with the MySQL client I'm using (Sequel Pro), but I get exactly the same message running from the command line.

Am I making some kind of ridiculously simple mistake that I just can't see? Or does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be causing the error? Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: You can only use `if` in program blocks, such as stored procedures, functions, and triggers.  It is not recognized in other contexts.

Comment: there is, however, an inline if statement.  Good example here: http://timmurphy.org/2009/08/13/inline-if-and-case-statements-in-mysql/

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff - very helpful! Reading the docs back now this point is sort of understandable there, but nowhere is it particularly explicit (well, IMO!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in [@Gordon Linoff's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27689472/mysql-if-then-syntax-error#comment43792138_27689472), MySQL's [`IF` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/if.html) is only valid within [stored programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/stored-programs-views.html) (i.e. code that is stored within and then invoked by MySQL in response to particular conditions); that is to say, it cannot be used in the manner that you are attempting.

However, one rarely *needs* to use `IF` in SQL.

This may seem strange to people who are familiar with *procedural* languages (in which one's code describes the algorithm and process steps to be executed—thus control-flow constructs like "if…then…else" are invaluable), but SQL is a *declarative* language (in which one's code describes the desired result and *not* how that result should be achieved—thus attempting to use control-flow constructs almost certainly arises from a misunderstanding of the language).

By way of example, in a procedural language one might tell the computer to perform a comparison, inspect the result and then output a value if the result meets certain criteria:

```
for each x in Set
  if x < 10 then
    output x
```

By contrast, in a declarative language one just tells the computer what result one wants:

```
output x from Set if x < 10
```

Or, in SQL:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name < 10
```